# Prove the existence of a bijection using Schröder-Bernstein theorem

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove the existence of a bijection, $h : (0,1] \rightarrow [0 , \infty)^{2}$.
For this I plan to use to use the Schröder-Bernstein theorem and find 2 injections on

$f : (0,1] \rightarrow [0 , \infty)^{2}$

$g : [0, \infty)^{2} \rightarrow (0 , 1] $

However, I am not able to come up with valid injections, please help.

Comment: You should provide some more details about what you've tried. For example, did you at least find $f$?

Comment: Another user just asked the exact same question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852340/is-there-a-bijection-between-1-infty-and-0-infty2#3852340) I wonder if this is from homework or an active online exam.

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly find $f$.

For $g$, consider the case of $[0,1)^2$. For $(x,y) \in [0,1)^2$, write $x=0,x_1x_2\cdots$ and $y=0,y_1y_2\cdots$ their decimal representations (such that the sequence $(x_n)$ or $(y_n)$ don't end by $999999 \cdots$). Then define $g^\prime(x,y)=0,x_1y_1x_2y_2x_3y_3 \cdots$ in decimal representation. The function $g^\prime$ is injective and you can construct $g$ using $g^\prime$.

Comment: I understand the part where $(x,y) \in [0,1)^{2} $, however for the remaining, I am still confused, could you please elaborate a bit on this.

Comment: Using an injection $[0,\infty) \to [0,1)$, define an injection $h : [0,\infty)^2 \to [0,1)^2$, then take $g=g^\prime \circ h$

Answer (score 0):

More hints and logic scraps that the OP can use to explicitly define an injection

$\tag 1 g : [0, \infty)^{2} \rightarrow (0 , 1]$

Working with the boundary of the domain of (still to be defined) $g$ is annoying, so we'll start with

$\quad g(0,0) = 1$

and define bijective correspondences

$\quad g(V) \simeq (.5, .75) \quad \text{ where } V = \{0\} \times (0, \infty)$

and

$\quad g(H) \simeq (.75, 1) \quad \text{ where } H = (0, \infty) \times \{0\}$

OK, looking to extend $g$ to an injection on what remains,

$\quad  (0, \infty)^{2} \rightarrow (0 , .5)$

Since $(0 , 1) \simeq (0 , .5)$ the problem is reduced to finding an injection

$\quad  (0, \infty)^{2} \rightarrow (0 , 1)$

Let $U = \{(x,y) \mid x,y \in (0,\infty) \land x^2 + y^2 \lt 1\}$.

Since $ (0, \infty)^{2} \simeq U$ the problem is reduced to finding an injection

$\quad  U \rightarrow (0 , 1)$

Since $U \subsetneq (0,1) \times (0,1)$ the problem is reduced to finding an injection

$\quad (0,1) \times (0,1) \rightarrow (0 , 1)$

But AlexL's answer supplies a 'splicing' technique, allowing us to write

$\quad (0,1) \times (0,1) \simeq (0 , 1)$

So the building scrap material has been supplied.